# Event Delegation in Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi

As I am trying to learn a new language **Delphi** I need some assistance.

Possible technique but do not know how to implement:

Below is use of Event Delegation in Delphi:

```
type
  TMyProcEvent = procedure(const AIdent: string; const AValue: Integer) of object;
  TMyFuncEvent = function(const ANumber: Integer): Integer of object;
```

In the class, you can add a DoEvent (rename for the proper event). SO you can call the DoEvent internally. The DoEvent handles the possibility that an event is not assigned.

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FMyProcEvent : TMyProcEvent;
    FMyFuncEvent : TMyFuncEvent;
  protected
procedure DoMyProcEvent(const AIdent: string; const AValue: Integer);
function DoMyFuncEvent(const ANumber: Integer): Integer;

  public
    property MyProcEvent: TMyProcEvent read FMyProcEvent write FMyProcEvent;
    property MyFuncEvent: TMyFuncEvent read FMyFuncEvent write FMyFuncEvent;
  end;

procedure TMyClass.DoMyProcEvent(const AIdent: string; const AValue:   Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(FMyProcEvent) then
    FMyProcEvent(AIdent, AValue);
  // Possibly add more general or default code.
end;


function TMyClass.DoMyFuncEvent(const ANumber: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(FMyFuncEvent) then
    Result := FMyFuncEvent(ANumber)
  else
    Result := cNotAssignedValue;
end;
```

**Update in Delphi**

Below is the code which I have achieved in **Delphi**

This is my myclass.pas

```
unit myclass;

interface

type
  TEvent1 = procedure() of Object;
  TMyClass = class(TComponent)
    private
 FValue: Integer;
 FEvent: TNotifyEvent; // could be TEvent1 aswell
 procedure SetValue(const AValue: Integer);
 function GetValue(): Integer;
  protected
 procedure DoFireEvent();
  public
 constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
 property Value: Integer read GetValue write SetValue;
  published
 property OnEvent: TNotifyEvent read FEvent write FEvent;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyClass.SetValue(const AValue: Integer);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
  if AValue < 6 then DoFireEvent();
end;

function TMyClass.GetValue(): Integer;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoFireEvent();
begin
  if Assigned(FEvent) then FEvent(Self);
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(AOwner: TComponent); 
begin
  FEvent := nil;
  FValue := 10;
end

end.
```

And below is form11.pas, which has form controls:
        unit form11;

```
interface

uses
   Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,myclass;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyClassEventHandler(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.MyClassEventHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Value is now below 6: ' + IntToStr(TMyClass(Sender).Value));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myclass: TMyClass;
begin
  myclass := TMyClass.Create(nil);
  try
    myclass.OnEvent := MyClassEventHandler;
    myclass.Value := 9; // no event
    myclass.Value := 3; // event
    myclass.Value := 8; // no event;

    // show it's current value
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(myclass.Value));
  finally
    myclass.Free();
  end;

end.
```

> > I am getting the following errors in myclass.pas:
> >
> > **[Error] myclass.pas(7): Undeclared identifier: 'TComponent'**
> >
> > **[Error] myclass.pas(10): Undeclared identifier: 'TNotifyEvent'**
> >
> > **[Error] myclass.pas(16): Cannot override a static method**
> >
> > **[Error] myclass.pas(37): Incompatible types**
> >
> > **[Error] myclass.pas(46): ';' expected but 'END' found**

**Final code after all the learning and googling:**

```
unit myclass;

interface

uses   Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

    type
  MyInterfce = procedure (var AValue: Integer; var isbreak: Boolean) of object;

  TMyClass = class
  private
    OnEvent: MyInterfce;
  public
     constructor Create();

     procedure DoFireEvent();
  published

    property MyEvent  :  MyInterfce read OnEvent write OnEvent;
  end;

implementation


procedure TMyClass.DoFireEvent();
var i : integer;
isbreaked: boolean;
begin
  isbreaked:= false;
  for i :=0 to 5 do
  begin
    if assigned (MyEvent) then MyEvent(i,isbreaked);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    if  isbreaked = true then break;
    Sleep(1000);
  end;
  //ShowMessage(IntToStr(integer(i)));
    //for i :=0 to 20 do
  //FEvent := IntToStr(i);
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create();
begin
;
end;

end.


unit form11;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,myclass;

type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
Button1: TButton;
Edit1: TEdit;
Button2: TButton;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure MyClassEventHandler(var value:Integer; var isbreak: Boolean);
procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
{ Private declarations }
  public
{ Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.MyClassEventHandler(var value:Integer;var isbreak:     Boolean);
begin
    Edit1.Text:=IntToStr(value);

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myclass: TMyClass;
begin
  myclass := TMyClass.Create();
  try
myclass.MyEvent := MyClassEventHandler;
myclass.DoFireEvent();
  finally
    myclass.Free();
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myclass: TMyClass;
begin
  myclass.FreeInstance();
  end;

end.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello @DavidHeffernan, please see my code after Update ikn Delphi. I am facing some errors. My question is use of event delegation in Delphi. I have done the code in C#, need help with Delphi!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not in fact related to event delegation, and the C# code is not relevant. You've just got some banal compiler errors.

Let's read the error messages and see if we can understand what they say.

> [Error] myclass.pas(7): Undeclared identifier: 'TComponent'

You refer to `TComponent`, but the compiler does not recognise that identifier. Why not? Because you did not use the unit which defines it.

You need to add units to a `uses` clause so that the compiler can find these symbols. Looking at the first two errors, `TComponent` and `TNotifyEvent` require that you use `Classes`. The other errors are just consequences of `TComponent` not being available to the compiler.

Make the following change to your unit:

```
unit myclass;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type
....
```